# Hiding raw pointers by providing a "proxy" pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there a way to hide a raw pointer behind a "proxy" or "fake" pointer that will provide access to the functionality of the raw pointer without revealing it's address?

The managing class for the raw pointer might look as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class hidden_ptr
{
public:
    hidden_ptr(T *RawPointer);
    ~hidden_ptr();

    T *get()
    {
       return new proxy_pointer<T>(raw_pointer)
    }
};
```

Then to use it:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    void do_bar();
    void do_bar2();
};

int main()
{
    Foo *raw_pointer = new Foo();
    hidden_ptr<Foo> hidden(raw_pointer);

    Foo *proxy = hidden.get();

    proxy->do_bar();
    proxy->do_bar2();

    delete proxy; //The raw pointer is still safe till the hidden object destructs
}
```

If there is a way, what would the proxy_ptr look like?

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes, there is a way to do it in most cases.

Comment: Sounds like a [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you might look into "smart pointers."

Comment: @Steve It would be similar to a shared_ptr however instead of returning the actual raw_pointer and reference counting, it would return the proxy_pointer thereby hiding the actual address

Comment: You might want to overload `operator->` for such task.

Comment: whats the benefit of hiding the address?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x By hiding the address you cannot unintentionally delete the object pointed to by the pointer and it can also help facilitate in memory management. If the proxy pointer is deleted that is perfectly ok as the actual object is still secure.

Comment: @Alex ah, you want something like the (proposed) std::observer_ptr

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Something like that, however I guess it would be more like an unique_ptr providing an observer_ptr via `.get()`. Although if the observer_ptr didn't have the `release()` and `get()` functions this would be very close to what I am looking for. The question is then how would one go about implementing such an observer_ptr

Comment: Deleted my answer, because even overloading `operator->` only does not protect from getting the address, because `operator->` can be called directly returning the address. Now I don't think there is any safe way to do this even if the type to hold is behaving cooperatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to satisfy the combination of requirements that you provided so far is to make class `Foo` a dual-mode class of sorts: it should be able to act as the primary (hidden) object, as well as a public proxy to itself, i.e. to another `Foo` object.

A fairly "ugly" implementation of that might look as follows

```
class Foo
{
    Foo *redirect_to = nullptr;
    Foo(Foo *redirect_to) : redirect_to(redirect_to) { ... }

public:
    Foo() { ... }
    ~Foo() { ... }

    Foo *get_proxy() { return new(this); }

    void do_bar() {
      if (redirect_to) {
        return redirect_to->do_bar();
      ...
    }

    void do_bar2() {
      if (redirect_to) {
        return redirect_to->do_bar2();
      ...
    }

    ...
};
```

After that you will be able to create and delete proxies accessible through a `Foo *` pointer. Whether to wrap such proxies into smart pointers of any kind is up to you - this is beside the point.

```
int main()
{
    Foo *raw_pointer = new Foo();

    Foo *proxy = raw_pointer->get_proxy();

    proxy->do_bar();
    proxy->do_bar2();

    delete proxy;
}
```

Again, you can add your `hidden_ptr` into the mix, if you wish.

A closer look at the above immediately suggests it can be implemented much more elegantly through a pImpl-style implementation, in which *all* objects become proxies pointing to a hidden implementation class. But it appears that you don't like that approach for some reason (which I was not able to figure out so far).

Comment: I believe you are right. It's unfortunate that there is no nice way of doing the redirection applying it in a template style.

Answer (score 0):

There are two: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Although the general intent behind them is more to provide easy resource-management, they satisfy what you request.

Comment: They are not quite what I am looking for as a unique_ptr doesn't allow access to the raw pointer (which is what I want) however it doesn't have the ability to provide a raw which can be passed around (which I want). The shared_ptr does provide the raw pointer but if you called delete on the raw pointer it would delete the underlying memory

Comment: @Alex: You began by saying that you want to *hide* the raw pointer. Now you are saying that you want to acces the raw pointer and pass it around. That's kinda self-contradictory. Once you provide direct access to raw pointer, it is no longer hidden. Firstly, you need to decide what exactly it is that you want.

Comment: @AnT I do want to hide the "actual" raw pointer, but I want to pass around the "proxy" raw pointer that can be deleted at will without any consequences to the "actual" pointer

Comment: You can get the raw pointer from both smart pointers using the `get`-method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's very easy. Just make a pointer member private, then overload the * and -> operators to dereference the private member. But it's also a pointless thing to do, an extreme case of "Chinese box" programming where you create "abstractions" which are in fact just aliases or wrappers to other data types.

Comment: Do you consider the proposed `std::observer_ptr` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) an example of that  "Chinese box" programming?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class hidden_ptr
{
public:
    hidden_ptr() = delete;
    hidden_ptr(hidden_ptr const&) = delete;
    hidden_ptr(T data) : ptr_(new T{data}) {}
    void operator=(hidden_ptr const&) = delete;
    ~hidden_ptr() {delete ptr_;}

    T* operator->() {return ptr_;};
    void reset(T data) {this->~hidden_ptr(); ptr_ = new T{data};}
    void set(T value) {*ptr_ = value;}
    T get() {return *ptr_;}

private:
    T* ptr_;
};

class A
{
public:
    void print() {std::cout << "A::print" << std::endl;}    
};

int main() 
{
    hidden_ptr<int> ptr_int(5);
    hidden_ptr<A> ptr_a(A{});
    ptr_int.reset(10);
    std::cout << ptr_int.get() << std::endl;
    ptr_a->print(); 
}
```

This way user can't access pointer address. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Sadly it's wrong : user can access pointer through "operator->()" method =/